# How to access one object from another form in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say I have "Form1" and "Form2", both are forms.
In Form1 there are the Main Class and the Main method.

In Form1 I create an object like:

```
public myobject ob1 = new myobject();
```

But then, in Form2, I have this code:

```
 private void bdCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ob1.status = 1; // I can't access ob1 !!!
    }
```

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The correct answer depends on this. Generally, you'll need an instance of `Form1`, but it may be impossible in your case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an instance of `Form1`. Normally if you have displayed this form you have instantiated it (`Form1 form1 = new Form1()`). Then you could operate on this instance and access public members:

```
form1.ob1.status = 1;
```

Another possibility is to have your `Form2` constructor take a `Form1` instance:

```
public class Form2: Form
{
    private readonly Form1 _form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    private void bdCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.ob1.status = 1;
    }
}
```

and then when you are somewhere inside `Form1` and want to create and show `Form2`:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I can't access Form1, that was the form that was automaticaly created when starting a new WinForm Application in VS2010. I didn't istanced it.

Comment: @dysoco, well in this case you could pass this form1 instance to the constructor of Form2 when you instantiate it. That way you will have access to it. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more ? Do I use "Form1 form1 = new Form1()" in Form2 ?

Comment: in Form1, just use "this" to pass to Form2.

Comment: @dysoco, *it saids*??? Could you be a little more specific like for example posting the exact error message you are getting as well as the code you are trying to compile/run?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well, I didn't want to specifie because my VS is in Spanish, but here are the code errors: 

error CS1002
error CS1519
error CS1519
error CS1518

And the code is exactly what you posted

Comment: @dysoco, OK, then post your entire code as you seem to be missing some C# fundamentals like terminating your statements with `;`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ... I had changed them, but I didn't compile it, and I just copied the errors, I know how to fix the semi-colons.

Comment: @dysoco, our discussion here is no longer constructive without you showing your source code.