# Add Items in ComboBox using Textbox Value from another form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 Window Forms, `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` has a `ComboBox` and `Form2` has a `Textbox` and a `Button`.

I hope you can help me with this one. What I would like to happen is, if I input a string value in the `TextBox` in `Form2` and hit the `Button1` that is also located in my `Form2`, the value of that `TextBox` will be an item for my `ComboBox` that is located in my `Form1`.

I just would like to ask if is there any way that we can do this? Could you provide an example for me? I'm looking forward to your help.

Comment: This question (many alternatives) has been asked and answered millions of times before. Check a couple of them and pick the most lovely.

Comment: Im sorry about that, let me check on that. But, if you would mind could you send me some links of it also sir?

Comment: Wait for it. During review, your post will most probably be marked as a duplicate and you will get the link as well :) [Here is one anyways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517232/how-to-access-one-object-from-another-form-in-c)

Comment: Sir, it didn't solve my problem still :(

Comment: You should put a way for you to access the instance of the `Form2` from `Form1` or at least a method in `Form2` which can be accessed/called by `Form1` to get the value of the `TextBox` in `Form2`. By doing so, you can get the value of your `TextBox` from `Form1` easily. Otherwise, you can tell `Form1` by some other means (a little more difficult) such as transferring a string with TCP-IP or putting your value in text file... etc...

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you'd include what attempt code you have so far, and/or what obstacles you're encountering, but nonetheless this is a simple problem that's a bit difficult to search for, so hopefully this will help.

First, I'm assuming you've instantiated and displayed both forms. Next you'll want to find the Designer.cs (formNameHere.Designer.cs) file in your Solution Explorer, then locate the variable declaration for your combo box (should be near the bottom). Change its access modifier from 'private' to something more appropriate.

Now go back to your Form1 code file and add this to your button click event handler:

```
form2.comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

... where 'form2', 'comboBox1', and 'textBox1' are your child form, combo box, and text box from which you are sending the new combo box item.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Sir, my Form1 has a comboBox only and my Form2 has 1 textBox and 1 button.

Comment: ... then switch the instructions form Form1 to Form2.

Answer (score -1):

I think best option is to communicate between the forms through `events`. So on button click event trigger an event and subscribe to it from the Form1. When the event is raised, add the text to the combobox

In Form2:

```
internal event EventHandler<string> NewItemToAdd;
void button1_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(NewItemToAdd != null)
        NewItemToAdd(textbox.Text);
}
```

In Form1 subscribe to the event `NewItemToAdd` and add the text to your combobox when the event is raised